# robot types the wrong chars

Tags: java, awt, keypress, awtrobot

I got a java robot to type characters, however it prints stuff like:

> .. 5./.   ..   .. //5  /   /55/ /.. ..5.. .. 5 5 . 5.

Instead of the wanted string.
Does someone know how to avoid this?

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.AWTException;

Robot robot;

String txt = "o noes ";
char[] chars;

void setup() {

  chars = txt.toCharArray();

  try {
    robot = new Robot();
  } 
  catch(AWTException e) {
  }
  robot.setAutoDelay(1);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    int c = chars[(int)random(chars.length)];
    robot.keyPress(c);
    robot.keyRelease(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the `random` method?  It's not a built-in, and I don't see any static imports...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: it works when using processing which is awsome for small things.
See www.processing.org, really worth looking into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider this kind of lengthy but it works http://pastebin.com/p0BdJxpy

Answer (score 2):

You have to use values from the `KeyEvent` class, not characters, for `keyPress`, as per the javadoc for `keyPress`.

```
KeyEvent ke = new KeyEvent(<various parameters>);
ke.setKeyChar('a');
int code = ke.getKeyCode();
```

Comment: is there a quick way to convert 'z' to 'KeyEvent.VK_Z' etc?